# IOS 6 opens RSS feeds in Podcast app - how do I prevent this?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, rss

When I click on an RSS feed link in Safari in iOS, instead of opening the RSS page it opens the podcast app, which is not helpful and very annoying. Is there a way to disable this automatic redirect to the podcast app?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as far as I know (and that is usually enough ;), you can not change the default app that opens the RSS feed.
Personally I use the Downcast podcast app, to add the rss feeds from `Safari` to my Downcast app is as follows:

- Go to the specific website and find you URL
- Press and hold the rss-link you are interested in
- Choose `Copy`
- Now go to your RSS app and paste the URL

[image: Press and hold rss link]

Comment: Thanks.  That's about the conclusion I was reaching too.  Even apple's official rss feeds at apple.com/rss behave this way, so it doesn't appear there is a way to indicate in the XML that it's a feed and not a podcast.  Oh well.  Got to work with what you've got.